# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: bin

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to VueJS.
Hi although my app is working I am getting this error in my console which blocks the jQuery.

v-for="message in messages" looping throught the object and trying to show the object. but getting this error Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: bin

```
<li v-for="message in messages" class="conversation-item">
<div class="" v-bind:class="message.direction" id="direction" title="other">
    <div class="conversation-avatar">
        <img class="rounded"
          width="36" height="36"
          src="assets/images/messenger-img.jpg"
          alt="">
        </div>
    <div v-if="message.contentType == 'file'" class="conversation-messages">
        <div class="conversation-message">
            <a class="file-link" :href="message.content" :title="message.fileName" :download="message.fileName">
                <div v-if="message.fileType == 'fileType'" class="message file-thumbnail" v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: "url(" + message.content + ")", }'>
                </div>
                <div v-else class="message.file-thumbnail" v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: "url(" + message | filterFile + ")", }'>
                </div>
                <div class="file-info"> 
                    <span class="file-name">@{{ message.fileName }}</span> 
                </div>
            </a>
            </div>
        <div class="conversation-timestamp">@{{ message.sentAt }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="conversation-messages">
        <div class="conversation-message">
            <a target="_blank" class="other_chat"></a><span>
                @{{ message.content  }}
            </span></div>
        <div class="conversation-timestamp">@{{ message.sentAt }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

actually this is a laravel blade so dont worry about @ sign

[image: screeshot of console]

Comment: From the error message, I'm assuming you have a typo somewhere else in your code where you've added a `v-bin` directive instead of `v-bind`.

Comment: Search for v-bin in your code based and share what you find .

Answer (score 33):

I had the same error after adding a v-bind directive.Turns out, I had a typo, and instead of **v-bind** I had **v-bin**.

In the future, if I receive a "Failed to resolve directive: X" message, I will look in my source for string *v-X*.

Comment: I've had this issue in the form of `Failed to resolve directive: disabled` which sounded cryptic, but was actually me thinking Vue is AngularJS and using `v-disabled` instead of `:disabled`...

Comment: I had this issue using v-modal instead of v-model....sighhhhhhh

Comment: This Reply is a lifesaver!

Comment: v-model was v-modal. thx bud!

Comment: v-model was v-mode, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the system once and restart it again, the problem will be solved. When using Vuetify, you must stop the system once after adding any component or property.